# NodeJS - any e-commerce solutions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-management-system, e-commerce

I'd like to know, are there any open-source NodeJS soultions? I mean ready for production, managed internet-shop cms? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is anything "production ready" like that, however there's a very interesting project that you could leverage called Gor.js which makes it "rails-like" (you can see at http://www.gorjs.org)

Answer (score 1):

it is in 0.6.18 now so far from being stable, platform is very young and you don't have a lot fo mature software. Expect more in 2-3 years :).

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there are frameworks like express.js which we can use to create apps easier. But expecting a ecommerce solution like magento , it's not mature enough and I think there are a lot of people and companies are making ecommerce solution with node.s, it will be out for maybe 2 or 3 years like Jakub Oboza said :)